# Why is localhost the only slow hostname on High Sierra OSX?

Tags: networking, macos, ipv6

I'm running a local django server on High Sierra. The GET fetches for JS files is 80ms for files on `127.0.0.1` but if I change it to `localhost` it is around 800ms per file. I've been able to get micah-mac.local to also show no delay. The issue happens in firefox as well, but I have primarily tested in chrome.

The bottleneck that Chrome shows is the the resource is being stalled under the timing tab. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Seriously, any other name I try works fine, besides localhost. I've disabled ipv6 for my network settings - this didn't change the speed. I've changed the order and combined lines of my host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost micah-mac.local # micah-mac.local is fast, localhost is slow
#255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1 localhost micah-mac.local # Enabling this line makes my micah-mac.local run as slow as localhost! Commenting it out runs fast.

fe80::1%lo0     localhost micah-mac.local # this line makes no difference if it is enabled or disabled
```

I've cleared my hostcache:

`chrome://net-internals/#dns` But that doesn't seem to fix anything.

`ping localhost` returns quickly.

My hostname seems ok:

```
micah at micah-mac in ~ (z)
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
micah-mac

micah at micah-mac in ~ (z)
$ scutil --get HostName
micah-mac.local
```

If i leave my host file blank `localhost` is still working and slow.